Why I am getting the error string indices must be integers, not 'str'?
I doing some analysis for football. And I have a large dataframe. From the dataframe I have made subdataframes based on two columns conditions. Everything is so far so good. But when I want to plot the events on pitch form the first subdataframe. But Iam getting the error "string indices must be integers, not 'str'". This is the dataframe below what Iam using




typeId
outcome
x
y
endX
endY




0
49
1
36.7
59.6
0.0
0.0


1
1
1
36.7
59.6
41.4
65.1


2
1
1
41.4
65.1
26.8
70.4


3
1
1
26.8
70.4
28.7
40.3


4
1
1
28.6
37.6
39.5
29.3


5
1
1
39.5
29.3
30.8
38.8


6
1
1
30.8
38.8
20.7
39.2


7
1
1
20.7
39.2
21.2
85.5


8
1
1
21.2
85.5
32.3
96.0


9
1
1
45.2
96.2
71.5
93.5


10
1
1
84.5
94.5
90.6
80.3


11
1
1
90.6
80.3
94.2
95.2


12
1
1
96.0
96.5
91.0
95.9


13
1
1
87.6
96.7
72.5
78.0


14
1
1
72.5
78.0
57.8
78.4


15
1
1
57.8
78.4
72.0
89.7


16
1
1
74.5
79.4
97.9
80.5


17
1
1
98.6
80.3
87.9
36.0


18
16
1
89.9
37.1
0.0
0.0



And this is what I want to do:
for event in df1:
    if event['typeId'] == 1:
        pitch.arrows(df1.x, df1.y, df1.endX, df1.endY, lw=1.0, color='green', zorder=1, ax=axs[0,0])
    elif event['type'] == 16:
        pitch.scatter(event.x, event.y, s=450, edgecolors='#b94b75', linewidths=0.6, c='white', marker='football', ax=axs[0,0])

And this is the TypeError
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 20
     18 # Plot the events
     19 for event in df1:
---> 20     if event['typeId'] == 1:
     21         pitch.arrows(df1.x, df1.y, df1.endX, df1.endY, lw=1.0, color='green', zorder=1, ax=axs[0,0])
     22     elif event['type'] == 16:

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

I have tried several loops but with no results. Any help would be fine. Thanks in advance


This is a misunderstanding of the for loop in a data frame. When you run a for loop based on a data frame, each element of columns becomes a variable in the loop (in your case, the variable in the loop is event).

You can easily verify this by adding print(event)' after the for event in df1: code.

for _, event in df1.iterrows(): should allow you to use the mechanism you want. However, using for loops in Pandas is often not efficient, so this could be an inefficient solution. However, it's unclear what exactly you're trying to do, so I can't suggest a more efficient solution.

What type of object do you think event represents?

I got your point and I have the following code which is working.
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
if df1['typeId'][index] == 1:
pitch.arrows(df1.x, df1.y, df1.endX, df1.endY, lw=1.0, color='green', zorder=1, ax=axs[0,0])
elif df1['typeId'][index] == 16:
pitch.scatter(df1.x, df1.y, s=450, edgecolors='#b94b75', linewidths=0.6, c='white', marker='football', ax=axs[0,0])
BUT the elif statement is plotting all the x and y of the df1. Why ? See the pitch. I want only the last row of df1 which is typeId 16. But now is plotting every x and y on the pitch

try: removing the ' ' from type and typeId
also try:
for event in df1:
        if typeId == 1:

            pitch.arrows(df1.x, df1.y, df1.endX, df1.endY, lw=1.0, color='green', zorder=1, ax=axs[0,0])

 22     elif type == 16:


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I found the solution
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row["typeId"]==1:
        pitch.arrows(row.x, row.y, row.endX, row.endY, lw=1.0, color='green', zorder=1, ax=axs[0,0])
    
    elif row["typeId"]==16:
        pitch.scatter(row.x, row.y, s=450, edgecolors='#b94b75', linewidths=0.6, c='white', marker='football', ax=axs[0,0])

